# How can I use MVVM light to execute a Command on a text box text change event

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, icommand, commandbinding

I have installed MVVMLIGHT but still somehow I can't access EventToCommand property even after adding the reference files and using the namespaces in xaml file

```
   xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com expression/2010/interactivity"
   xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight"

   <Textbox x:name="quantity">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
       //not working    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding quantityCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Textbox>
```

Even InvokeCommandAction would work but I m not getting that too.Plz show me.thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you bind the textbox to a property on the viewmodel and use the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: I am new to this.plz can u show me how

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36545/WPF-MVVM-Model-View-View-Model-Simplified

Comment: There wasn't anything with respective to a text box on the post

Comment: There's a clear XAML example with a textbox binding on its text properties. If you can't understand it, then you should read some basic tutorials before even trying to implement a full application, WPF is very hard in the beginning. A good site: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ it even teaches some advanced stuff.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using an event trigger instead of just binding the Text property and putting relevant code in the setter?